# Issue with files.upload using Slack's Node SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to upload a file through the [Slack SDK](https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk) but am having issues. Currently I'm getting a success with the code below:

```
const res = await client.files.upload({
  channel: 'CHANNEL',
  file: Buffer.from('hello'),
  filename: 'test.txt',
  filetype: 'text/plain',
});
```

The response looks something like:

```
{ ok: true,
  file:
   { id: 'FIDTM4IDM',
     created: 1568847491,
     timestamp: 1568847491,
     name: 'test.txt',
     title: 'test',
     mimetype: 'text/plain',
     filetype: 'text',
     pretty_type: 'Plain Text',
     ...
     ...
  }
}
```

However nothing is showing up in the channel when I check. I know things are configured correctly because I can post messages to the channel using the same configuration.

https://slack.dev/node-slack-sdk/web-api#upload-a-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You spelled the property wrong. It's called `channels` not `channel`. So the API will ignore your channel property and the file is uploaded to Slack, but not shared in channel.

Also make sure to use channel IDs only. Channel names are not supported.

Comment: Ah nice catch, the method that has `channel` instead of `channels` was on the @slack/web-api npm readme and through me off, but I see now that on the method itself it uses the plural. much appreciated.